# How to draw using openGL in SCNNodeRendererDelegate in scenekit

Tags: ios, opengl-es, scenekit

Currently I am creating line segments using below code( while line primitive .Line)

```
line = SCNGeometry(sources: [source], elements: [element])
```

I need to support line width, i can't use gllinewidth since it will apply line width to all line segments, each line segment(object) has different line width. So I thought of custom drawing using openGL, since scenekit provides a way to custom draw using below code.

```
extension MarkupViewController: SCNNodeRendererDelegate {

    func renderNode(_ node: SCNNode, renderer: SCNRenderer, arguments: [String : Any]) {

    }
}
```

I tried like almost a day figuring out how to use OpenGL commands inside renderNode method. but whatever i do can't draw anything on my node. 
Is there any sample code to draw a line or anything inside renderNode method.

Answer (score 0):

How about a pure SceneKit solution?

If you use a skinny SCNPlane or SCNCylinder or SCNBox, you can control the width of the connector.

Consider lowering the segment count if you use SCNCylinder. A high resolution won't be visible.